# Does Qmail utilize any of Sendmail's own configuration files?

Tags: sendmail, email

I am trying to run sendmail in tandem with qmail. Presently there is a symlink in the /usr/sbin/ directory pointing to the /var/qmail/sendmail binary. What do I have to change in the qmail configuration if I remove the symlink and rename sendmail.sendmail (I think this is the present name for sendmail's binary) to sendmail so my program can call it. What do I have to do to isolate the two installations aside from selecting a different port in sendmail's configuration?

Comment: just curious as to why you need both if your program is just calling sendmail to deliver email the qmail wrapper should work the same way?

Comment: It doesn't work quite the same. It's generating an error when OpenEmm calls it with the -q parameter:
Starting sendmails: listener sendmail: illegal option -- q

From what I've read it appears qmail uses a scaled down version of sendmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sendmail symlink is only provided to provide a sendmail-like interface to qmail, so 3rd party programs that expect sendmail. Qmail itself doesn't depend on it and should never call it.

Renaming/replacing it with a real sendmail binary should not affect qmail - it just means any 3rd party programs that call it will now be interacting with sendmail and not qmail.

Comment: Am I correct that Sendmail's own binary has been renamed sendmail.sendmail so as not to interfere with the symlink? If not, which binary is the correct original Sendmail binary, i.e. what has Qmail renamed it to?